# 1 Kings 22:7 NIV vs ESV

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 22:

> 6 So the king of Israel brought together the prophets—about **four hundred** men—and asked them, “Shall I go to war against Ramoth Gilead, or shall I refrain?”
>
> “Go,” they answered, “for the Lord will give it into the king’s hand.”

New International Version

> 7 But Jehoshaphat asked, "Is there **no longer** a prophet of the **LORD** here whom we can inquire of?"

The NIV Jehoshaphat here seems to be suspicious of the 400 prophets as NOT being the prophets of the LORD. The ESV Jehoshaphat seems more neutral.

English Standard Version

> 7 But Jehoshaphat said, “Is there not here **another** prophet of the LORD of whom we may inquire?”

Did Jehoshaphat doubt the words of the 400 prophets? Which translation is more faithful to the original?

Comment: *no longer* vs. *no other* - perhaps the term used in the [original languages](http://www.greekdoc.com/polyglot/1kings22.html#v7) does not make such fine distinctions ?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15906#v6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would literally translate 1 Kings 22:7 as:

> Jehoshaphat said, "not here a prophet of YHWH still that we may
> inquire of him?"

Thus we have a number of ways of rendering this in smoother, modern style:

- NIV: But Jehoshaphat asked, "Is there no longer a prophet of the LORD here whom we can inquire of?"
- ESV: But Jehoshaphat said, “Is there not here another prophet of the LORD of whom we may inquire?”
- BDB: But Jehoshaphat asked, “Is there not still a prophet of the LORD here of whom we can inquire?”
- NASB: But Jehoshaphat said, “Is there no longer a prophet of the LORD here, that we may inquire of him?”
- CSB: But Jehoshaphat asked, “Isn’t there a prophet of the LORD here anymore? Let’s ask him.”

All of these are correct - they reflect that Jehoshaphat sensed the 400 prophets were being sycophantic (he was correct - see v13).  Note especially the dialogue:

- Jehoshaphat asks (V5) to enquire of the **LORD** (YHWH)
- The prophets say (V6) to in the name of the **Lord** (adonay)
- Jehoshaphat again asks (V7) if these is someone who can prophesy in the same of the **LORD** (YHWH)

It was only then that Micaiah was summoned.